# kafka override advertised.host.name in client java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-producer-api

we have kafka 0.8.2.1 running on a single docker container. This is one of several containers set up to work together with docker compose. The docker compose also exposes the kafka 9092 port to the host machine.

The `advertised.host.name` of the kafka server is set to `kafka` and all the other containers can talk to it fine using this name.

The problem is that java test programs cannot send messages to the kafka server from the host machine.

- Using `kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer` errors
- Using `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer` hangs for ages  then errors

In both cases if I add an entry to the `/etc/hosts` file on the host machine it works fine. But this is not ideal, I would like anyone to be able to run these tests without messing with their `hosts` file.

So is there a way in a java Kafka producer to override the hostname/ip specified in the metadata. We only have one instance of kafka so there is no issue in getting the "right one".

On the [FAQ page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Whycan%27tmyconsumers%2Fproducersconnecttothebrokers%3F) it implies this can be done:

> In another rare case where the binding host/port is different from the
>   host/port for client connection, you can set advertised.host.name and
>   advertised.port for client connection

But there are no details how...

Or failing that a more general solution.
Is there a way to set a `hosts` entry in the java runtime environment? Without messing with system `/etc/hosts` files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to set up a dockerised broker so that it can talk to consumers and producers both in containers and on the host machine.

Set `advertised.host.name` in the dockerised broker to its docker-compose network IP address, and `bootstrap.servers` for any non-dockerised producers or consumers to `localhost`.

To get the compose network IP you can either specify a static IP in the compose file or set your container to run a shell command before starting kafka to get it.  The command I use is `ip -4 addr show scope global dev $(route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $8}' | head -1) | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d / -f 1`, but there are probably nicer ways.

Comment: OK, will try this out if I get time. Turns out couchbase (which we also use) has the same issue. I actually found a solution where you can programatically override DNS from within java, so we have used that to work around the problem.